# How to store multiple images in the database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to store multiple images in the database and also show them in the view. I have products table and images table which are related, in the images table I have a foreign key named(image). So far am getting this error `"Array to string conversion"`

Here are the codes

Controller

```
  public function store(Request $request) 
  { 

    $formInput=$request->all();
    $image=array();
    if($files=$request->file('image')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images',$name);
            $image[]=$name;

        }

    }
          product::create(array_merge($formInput,
       ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
       'image' => $image

    ])); 
    return redirect()->back();
```

Blade

```
  <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple class="form-control">
```

Product.php

```
   public function products()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Images', 'image');
  }
```

Images.php

```
   public function images()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'image');
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're experiencing?

Comment: The problem is it  stores one image I wanted to store multiple@SimonC

Comment: Okay, that's the behaviour you're experiencing and the expected behaviour is different. Is there an error? An exception, error code, etc? What does Request look like? Is the Request object the same as the HTTP request? We need more info.

Comment: This is ther error am getting `"Array to string conversion"` @SimonC

Comment: Can you please tell where you are getting "Array to string conversion" this error ?

Comment: I'm getting that error from here https://imgur.com/BtnDK93 @SagarSainkar

Comment: also after "  if($files=$request->file('image')){    " this line try dd($files); and check how may files are getting form front end

Comment: It shows two files like this `array:2 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#289 ▶}
  1 => UploadedFile {#291 ▶}
]`

Comment: ok , so multiple images are getting uploaded and stored in images table right ? can you show me what code you use to get product and show them ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the products table? @SagarSainkar

Comment: no ,I mean function for getting products and section of view where you show them

Comment: That is function called store but I created a requests and put other stuff inside the rule function check the updated question @SagarSainkar

Comment: can you just put full page screen shot of error page of browser ?

Comment: The full error https://imgur.com/BYT8TTC @SagarSainkar

Comment: check now i have updated my answer

Comment: @user11710915 Please do not post errors in form of images. Update your question with the error **in text form**. We don't always have time to open other links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of my Knowledge there is no bug in the file upload but While You are trying to Store

Like this or may by object oriented

it will be a bug

```
  $CreateArray = array_merge($request->all(), [
    'image' => $image
                ]);

                Model::create( $CreateArray);
```

So Since if you are uploading the Multiple files and You will get the array of file names but you can't store it as a array in databse  so

```
$CreateArray = array_merge($request->all(), [
    'image' => json_encode($image)
                ]);

                Model::create( $CreateArray);
```

EDITED

```
public function store(Request $request) 
  { 

    $formInput=$request->all();
    $image=array();
    if($files=$request->file('image')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images',$name);
            $image[]=$name;

        }

    }
          product::create(array_merge($formInput,
       [
'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'image' => json_encode($image)

    ])); 
    return redirect()->back();
```